# Why do I type parent::__construct?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

Each time I go to declare an extended class,

```
Class cookies extends Food{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Why am I using `parent::__construct()`?

Is this for inheritance? Does merely extending the class not inherit it's properties?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php . Basically you only need it, if your child class has a `_constructor` function.

Comment: How should we know why you use: `parent::__construct()` ?!

Comment: It simply calls the parent constructor. You should only call the parent constructor if it does something that you need. Usually you only need to do it if you want to do something in addition to (or in preparation of) what the parent constructor does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that's the sole content of your child class constructor, then you don't need to define the child constructor at all, and it will simply run the parent constructor.

If you do create a child class with a constructor, then that child constructor will run **instead of** the parent class constructor (even if it's just an empty body); so if you need to run the parent class's constructor **as well** then you need to call it explicitly by using `parent::__construct()`

Comment: So if the child class has requirements in addition to the parent's class, I would use parent::__construct() in the child's construct and  then include any required additions?

Comment: Precisely right, otherwise it's normally best not to bother defining a constructor in the child simply to call the parent constructor.... and remember that if the parent constructor requires arguments, and you have a child constructor as well, then it needs to accept those same arguments itself and pass them through when it calls the parent constructor

Comment: @MarkBaker well said. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its real simple. If you plan your child's class to have a `__construct`, then you need to decide, *"will I also want my parent's `__construct` to be inherited?"* if so, then you need to use `parent::__construct()`.

Take this example into consideration:

```
class Actions {

    function __construct() {
        echo "I can do even more actions and.. ";
    }

    function jump() {
        return "hop hop";
    }

    function eat() {
        return "munch munch";
    }
}

class Humans extends Actions {

    function __construct() { //this will overwrite the parents construct
        echo "I am a human and ...";
    }


    function talk() {
        return "I can talk";
    }

}

class Dogs extends Actions {

    function __construct() { //this will NOT overwrite the parents construct
        parent::__construct();
        echo "I am a dog and ...";
    }


    function bark() {
        return "I can bark";
    }

}
```

If we run a `Human()` function, we will get the following:

```
$human = new Humans();
var_dump($human->talk());

/*
RESULT:

I am a human and ...
string 'I can talk' (length=10)
*/
```

However, if we run a `Dogs()` function, we will get the following:

```
$dogs = new Dogs();
var_dump($dogs->bark());

/*
RESULT:
I can do even more actions and.. I am a dog and ...
string 'I can bark' (length=10)
*/
```